# Finding distinct rows across two tables: Full Outer Join more efficient than Union?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

When finding distinct rows across two tables where we can't necessarily ensure are pre-sorted, is it a good idea to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` rather than a `UNION`?  Are there any downsides to this approach?  If it is consistently faster, why does the query optimizer not choose the same plan for UNION that the `FULL OUTER JOIN` would use?

We were able to bring a specific production query from ~10 minutes to ~3 minutes by re-writing a `UNION` as a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  A `UNION` seems like the more intuitive way to write the logic, but upon exploring both options, I have observed that the `FULL OUTER JOIN` is more efficient in terms of both memory and CPU usage.

See the following scripts if you'd like to run a simplified and anonymized version of our production query:

**Setup script**

```
-- Create a 500K row table
SELECT TOP 500000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS id, v1.number % 5 AS val
INTO #t1
FROM master..spt_values v1
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values v2

-- Create a 5MM row table that will match some, but not all, of the 500K row table
SELECT TOP 5000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS id, v1.number % 5 AS val
INTO #t2
FROM master..spt_values v1
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values v2

-- Optionally, key both tables to see the impact it has on query plans and performance
-- Both queries end up with essentially the same plan and performance in this case
-- So that means that at least there is not a downside to using the FULL OUTER JOIN when the data is sorted
--ALTER TABLE #t1
--ADD UNIQUE CLUSTERED (id)
--ALTER TABLE #t2
--ADD UNIQUE CLUSTERED (id)
```

**FULL OUTER JOIN**

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` chooses the small of the two tables as the build side of a hash join, meaning that the memory usage is proportional to the size of the smaller table (500K rows).

```
-- CPU time = 3058 ms,  elapsed time = 783 ms.
-- MaxUsedMemory: 29016 KB
-- Table '#t1'. Scan count 5, logical reads 1301, physical reads 0
-- Table '#t2'. Scan count 5, logical reads 12989, physical reads 0
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(id), AVG(val)
FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS id, COALESCE(t1.val, t2.val) AS val
    FROM #t1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN #t2 t2
        ON t2.id = t1.id
        AND t2.val = t1.val
) x
GO
```

[image]

**UNION**

The `UNION` builds a hash table for a hash aggregate on the overall data set, meaning that the memory usage is proportional to the total number of distinct rows (5.4MM rows in this case; generally, at least the number of rows in the larger of the two tables).  The memory usage is over 10x greater than the `FULL OUTER JOIN`, and both CPU time and elapsed time are slower as well.  If I were to scale this up to the point that hash aggregate can't fit within a single query's memory grant, the performance difference would become huge (as it was in our large production query).

```
-- CPU time = 4651 ms,  elapsed time = 1188 ms.
-- MaxUsedMemory: 301600 KB
-- Table '#t1'. Scan count 5, logical reads 1301, physical reads 0
-- Table '#t2'. Scan count 5, logical reads 12989, physical reads 0
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(id), AVG(val)
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.val
    FROM #t1 t1
    UNION 
    SELECT t2.id, t2.val
    FROM #t2 t2
) x
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The semantics of the two queries are not the same - `UNION` removes duplicates, whereas the `FULL OUTER JOIN` will not:

```
DECLARE @T1 AS table (id bigint NULL, val integer NULL);
DECLARE @T2 AS table (id bigint NULL, val integer NULL);

INSERT @T1 (id, val) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT @T1 (id, val) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT @T2 (id, val) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT @T2 (id, val) VALUES (1, 1);

SELECT COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) AS id, COALESCE(t1.val, t2.val) AS val
FROM @t1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN @t2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
    AND t2.val = t1.val;

SELECT t1.id, t1.val
FROM @t1 t1
UNION 
SELECT t2.id, t2.val
FROM @t2 t2;
```

Output:

```
╔════╦═════╗
║ id ║ val ║
╠════╬═════╣
║  1 ║   1 ║
║  1 ║   1 ║
║  1 ║   1 ║
║  1 ║   1 ║
╚════╩═════╝

╔════╦═════╗
║ id ║ val ║
╠════╬═════╣
║  1 ║   1 ║
╚════╩═════╝
```

That said, the optimizer does not know many `FOJN` tricks, so it is always possible that there is a better way to express the query than the natural `UNION`. Only *commonly-useful* and *always-correct* transformations are implemented.

Note that with a unique constraint only on the larger table, the optimizer chooses a hash union, without expensive duplicate-removal on the probe input, that makes it choose Concat Union All in the question example:

```
ALTER TABLE #t2 
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ2 
UNIQUE CLUSTERED (id);

SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(x.id), AVG(x.val)
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.val
    FROM #t1 t1
    UNION
    SELECT t2.id, t2.val
    FROM #t2 t2
) AS x;
```

[image: Hash union plan]

The `FOJN` rewrite may well be a useful one in cases where you know there cannot be duplicates within each input set, but this condition is not enforced with a unique constraint or index (particularly on the large input).

If such a uniqueness guarantee does exist, and yet the optimizer does not select a Hash Union, you might try an `OPTION (HASH UNION)` hint, to see how it compares.